# Access database file of website application in forms application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a website where I had created a local SQL Server `.mdf` database file. I have another forms application and I want to use the same database in this application also. How can I do this? How to give the path of the database file in forms application

Comment: Is the site running on the same machine as the forms app?

Comment: yes it is running on the same machine

Comment: Put the SQL Server database **on the server** where it belongs and stop fiddling around with free-floating `.mdf` and you'll have no trouble at all to connect from multiple clients

Answer (score 1):

Your form app can use WebService to operation your database.